# How to print an NUnit test run's XML file as a nice-looking report on the command line?

Tags: nunit, reporting, pretty-print, nunit-console

I have a suite of NUnit tests.  When they finish, I get a `TestResults.xml` file.  This file is very large and dense; I'd like to be able to peruse a simple human-readable report of the underlying results.  I'm led to believe that the provided `nunit-console` program can do that, but I can't figure out how.

**How can I print the information described by `TestResults.xml` with `nunit-console`?**

Note that *running the tests* is not the problem; my problem is figuring out how to display the results on the command-line.  I can't change how the tests are run, but I can do whatever I want with the results file.

Comment: You can find various NUnit report generators on GitHub and other places. One example I was looking at the other day was `Ghpr.NUnit`, which generates a HTML/JS report. It requires some setup obviously, but after that it generates whenever you run tests using the `nunit-console`. The result is bit complex for my taste, and I'm still looking for a report generator that makes sense to me, but you might find it to be useful. You can view a sample report on the GitHub page. https://github.com/GHPReporter/Ghpr.NUnit

Answer (score 0):

The Test Result file isn't intended to be human-readable, except when used for debugging. It's a source for **all** the data about a test run from which human-readable reports may be generated.

There are two ways to generate a report

1. As a part of the test run itself.
2. After the run is finished, using the test result xml file.

Reports generated **as part of the test run** require a report writing extension. You would write such an extension following the documentation to produce the report in whatever format you require, like text or html, and give it a unique tag like`myreport`.

You would install your extension and could then run the console runner including an option like

```
 --result:somefile.html;format=myreport
```

As you may guess, creating your own extension is a relatively advanced use of NUnit.

Another option, if you are familiar with XSLT processing, is to use the built-in report format `user`, together with an XSLT transform. In that case, the option is something like

```
 --result:somefile.html;transform=mytransform.xslt
```

You can also produce a report **after the run is finished** using the XML output file. The NUnit console program is **not** used in this case. You must use some standard program for creating reports from NUnit output (or a generic program taking XSLT transforms) or write your own program.

Comment: Where can I find a pre-made XSLT or extension that'll make a report on the console?